# Sharing large data between threads without synchronizing access

Tags: java, multithreading

For example, consider a spell-checker that works on a large document while the user is typing new content into the document. To avoid delaying the user's work the spell-checking is done on a separate thread, but the spell-checker still needs access to the document. We could put all access to the document into synchronized blocks, but that would force the editing thread to slow down to accommodate the spell-checking thread.

In principle the user-interaction thread should never be blocked for any reason. If there are to be any delays suffered due to accessing the document from multiple threads, we want them to always happen in the spell-checking thread, but what sort of thread communication will guarantee that?

This same problem applies to more than just spell-checking. Whenever one thread is the primary owner of some data while another thread performs noncritical background computations on the data we face the same situation. I imagine that the solution is some sort of message-passing system where the secondary thread sends requests to the primary thread that are processed at the primary thread's own pace.

Comment: Have you tried using a lock?  If not, then how do you know that there is a performance problem?  I can't imagine why the spell check thread would ever need to hold a lock for more time that it takes to make a local copy of the latest update (sub-millisecond) or, for more time than it takes to notify the GUI thread of a spelling error (again, sub-millisecond).

Comment: Re, "some sort of message-passing,"  Unless the LMAX Disruptor is appropriate for your application (very high throughput, non-blocking, _bounded_ queue), then it's pretty likely that your message-passing is going to use some kind of lock anyway.

Comment: @jameslarge We want to design for performance, not wait for a problem once it is too late to fix it. In principle the UI thread should never block. We might get away with violating that principle for a spell-checker, but also maybe not. Even if we might not need it, It would be good to know how to do it properly so it won't cause a huge overhaul if we have to do it later.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to share some tricks I would use:

1. Use fair ReadWriteLock.
2. Make the lock fine-grained, to make no thread hold the lock for too long.
3. Move the time-consuming code outside the lock. It may require copy some task context.
4. Use Copy-On-Write in some case. For example, split your document to multiple small parts. Assume user is editing only one part. And the user is editing at normal human speed. Then you can make each part a Copy-On-Write collection. Even a cow collection of cow collections if you want to.